# A measure theory textbook that covers differentiation before integration

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am starting on learning measure theory . Out of the few books , that I had glanced into I had found one book which , before proceeding towards integration , had started  with few chapters covering topics on differentiation . But unfortunately , I am unable to recollect which book was that .  It seemed interesting to go through measure theory from differentiation perspective .

Does anyone know any such  textbook on measure theory which proceeds through differentiation (or from the perspective of differentiation) ?

Comment: After a quick check through the several dozen such books on my bookshelves, I found three such books: [**Real Functions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1124060154) by Casper Goffman (1953) (FYI, the amazon.com prices are ridiculous; I purchased it for $3.50 back in the early 1980s, and it can be found in a large number of university libraries), [**Introduction to Real Functions and Orthogonal Expansions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0195010744) by Béla Sz.-Nagy (1965; the first 374 pages deal with Lebesgue measure/integration), **(continued)**

Comment: @Dave L Renfro : Many many Thanks for your time and effort , Sir . I would try checking the table of contents for this books so as to confirm . Thanks a ton

Comment: and [**Functions of Real Variables**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00085GID0) by Edgar Jerome Townsend (1928). Probably the book by Béla Sz.-Nagy is closest to what I suspect you want. Goffman's book probably does too much with Borel sets, Baire functions, set theory, and other classical foundational material most people today are not much interested in (at least, not using the approach taken in Goffman's book, i.e. non-axiomatic set theoretic treatment), and Townsend's book is probably too old to be useful for a modern student who wants a more abstract treatment.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks , again

Comment: Another such book is the 1996 4th edition of [**A Primer of Real Functions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/088385029X) by Ralph P. Boas, revised and updated by Harold P. Boas. The 4th edition includes a new final chapter on Lebesgue integration written by Harold P. Boas (Ralph's son), so I guess the 4th edition could be considered an example, but since this book is rather unique in several ways (also well-known, so you may know of it already), it is probably not what you're looking for. FYI, the 1st, 2nd, 3rd editions were published in 1960, 1972, 1981.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro : Yes , I am aware of this book by Ralph Boas. But I will definitely look into it .